# WCF: The remote server returned an error: '(417) Expectation Failed' and '(503) Server Unavailable'

Tags: c#, wcf

First of all, I've tried a lot in google and statckoverflow, but it still fails. I hope to help me. Thank you.

---

I am getting the following error when call an WCF Service from my WebClient.

> The remote server returned an error: **(417) Expectation Failed**.

I have tried changing web.config of my WebClient, with the following settings, but still no success.

```
<system.net>
    <settings> 
        <servicepointmanager expect100continue="false" />
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

Following this change, I'm getting the error:

> The remote server returned an error: **(503) Server Unavailable**.

Note 1: Through the **WCF Test Client** or another console client works fine. Why??

Note 2: Server and Web Client hosted in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because the setting of a **duplicate binding** on IIS Site.

After remove it, works fine.
[image: Duplicate Binding]